# iOS App Approval without localized app description?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, itunes-store, localized

I want to publish my iPhone App in both Japanese and Chinese languages. I have localized the content to the respective languages. However, the app metadata description and iAP descriptions are still in English. Will my app be approved?

Comment: Is your question: "Will Apple approve my app?" OR "How can I localize my description?" Please clarify for better responses and to avoid having your question put on hold.

Comment: You are right my question doesn't clearly explain. Thanks;

Comment: And the answer is yes of course, why wouldn't they? There's no regulation against not localizing your app. Also keep in mind that customers see the app description and metadata *before* they see your app!

Comment: I agree with @Sam.  Localization is a choice of the developer, what verbage you choose to include in *your* app is *your* choice, not theirs.  Just my 2 cents.  You could also check if there are apps that you know are localized to these same languages that don't have their app descriptions localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course! Why wouldn't Apple approve it? There's no regulation against not localizing your app.

However, you should keep in mind that customers see the app description and metadata **before** they see your app. So, chances are if a customer sees your app description is not localized, they aren't going to bother downloading it to see if it's localized.

Also, a good point from [@SlyRaskal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851191/ios-app-approval-without-localized-app-description#comment31278880_20851191):

> Localization is a choice of the developer, what verbiage you choose to include in your app is your choice, not theirs. Just my 2 cents. You could also check if there are apps that you know are localized to these same languages that don't have their app descriptions localized.

Comment: Quote "chances are if a customer sees your app description is not localized, they aren't going to bother downloading it to see if it's localized."  A good point